# Angular - How to make canActivate to await for promise response?

Tags: angular, promise

I try to check in CanActivate gurad if user is logged in.
If yes, then I navigate him to some page.
If not, then I navigate him to login page.
I use promise.

I have a service named **LoginService**:

```
export class LoginService {

  urlcheck = 'http://localhost:80/isconnected.php';
  resultCheck;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router)
  {
  }

  async checkLogin()
  {
    const x = await this.updateConnectedState();
    return x;
  }

  updateConnectedState()
  {
    //formData here...
    return this.http.post(this.urlcheck, formData).toPromise()
      .then(
        (response) =>
        {
          this.resultCheck = response; 
          console.log(response);
          return this.resultCheck.state; //state is true/false
        },
        (error) => 
        { 
            console.log(error); 
            return false;  
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

**the canActivate Gurad:**

```
export class BackHomeGuardService implements CanActivate
{
  constructor(private logService: LoginService, private router: Router)
  {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>|boolean
  {
    const result = this.logService.checkLogin();
    console.log( result);

    if (result)
    {
      console.log('true');
      // navigate to hom page
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('false');
      // navigate to login page
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

The guard canActivate function always return true.
I checked in console and the the promise result is:

```
__zone_symbol__state: null
__zone_symbol__value: []
```

I want to make the canActive await for result before it will do something.
What if my backend (php code file) will take 30 seconds to be completed?
I need a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to `CanActivate`'s type:

```
export declare interface CanActivate {
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree;
}
```

the method `canActivate` can return Observable, Promise or boolean.

You can simply return your `checkLogin()` call like:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>|boolean {
    return this.logService.checkLogin();
}
```

and everything will work.

---

**UPDATE**

answering the question *"how do I handle the returned boolean in my canActivate"* from comments

The idea of the CanActivate is to restrict the access to some routes due to a certain condition. You *can* perform some side-effects (but I'm not sure how they will be displayed, unless it's a console.log) by chaining your Promise or Observable:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>|boolean {
    return this.logService
      .checkLogin()
      .then(canLogin => {
         console.log('Can user login:', canLogin);
         // perform you side effects here
      })

}
```

Comment: it does not work... I want to handle the result too

Comment: it does working only if I use: return this.logService.checkLogin(); I want to handle the boolean in canActivate. how to do that?

Comment: The idea of canActivate is to show or hide certain routes according to some condition.
What do you mean by `handle the boolean` (what are the operations you want to perform)?

Comment: It doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the return type of the canActivate method:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree
```

}

It can return a simple boolean or a Promise, or an Observable. Also, I don't think you need to convert the Observable to a Promise inside your LoginService.

Comment: I change that to observable and in canActivate I use return this.logService.checkLogin(); But I don't know how to handle the boolean result...

Answer (score 0):

canActivate can work with observable so you can map query result to return observable in this way

```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class LoginService {

  urlcheck = 'http://localhost:80/isconnected.php';
  resultCheck;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
  }

  checkLogin(): Observable<boolean> {

    //formData here...
    return this.http.post(this.urlcheck, formData).pipe(
      map(
        (response) => {
          this.resultCheck = response;
          console.log(response);
          return this.resultCheck.state; //state is true/false
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          console.log(error);
          return of(false);
        })
      );
  }
}

export class BackHomeGuardService implements CanActivate
{
  constructor(private logService: LoginService, private router: Router)
  {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>
  {
    return this.logService.checkLogin();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`canActivate` can have the following return type: `boolean`, `Promise<boolean>`, or `Observable<boolean>`.

Since you already have `checkLogin()` to return a `Promise` that will resolve to `true/false`. Let's stick with `Promise` or `Observable`. As the others have already answered, you can absolutely just return `this.logService.checkLogin()`

```js
   canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
      return this.logService.checkLogin();
   }
```

Now, I see that you want to navigate somewhere else based on the `checkLogin()` value as well. And I'd suggest to convert the `Promise` to `Observable` so you can leverage `tap` operator. You can do it like the following:

```js
   return fromPromise(this.logService.checkLogin()).pipe(
      tap(isLogin => {
         if (!isLogin) {
            // not login. navigate to login page
         }
      })
   )
```

We do not really want to navigate somewhere on `true` because when it's true, the Guard will navigate the user to the route that is being guarded.

Comment: and if I want to use observable instead of promise? thanks

Comment: `fromPromise` is the way to go

Comment: or you meant you wanted to use `Promise` instead of `Observable`?